# In a PACT test can I match a request that contains some Base64 encoded content

Tags: pact

I'm trying to write my first PACT consumer test and the request body contains (among other things) a signed JWT.

The issue is that the JWT contains a unique ID and a timestamp that change on every request, so when I set up the pact with a hardcoded expected request the test fails due to the request bodies not matching.

I could potentially refactor things so that in the test we always use the same ID and timestamp, but it would be nice to be able to specify in the test the request body can vary in this way.

I have found documentation on creating JSON bodies with various matching rules, but my request body is only JSON within the JWT once it is Base64 decoded.

Is what I want to do possible?

(Bonus question for curiosity - if it is possible how does that work with the producer side of the testing?)